# Merge multiple Birt reports into one

Tags: birt

I have seen all the samples of the Birt reports available in eclipse - they do not say how to have multi paged Birt reports - as in what if I have ten tables  - and all of them producing different data - These cannot be put in one page.

So how do I add multiple pages to one report?. Or if that is not possible - how do I club multiple reports (Each report containing one page design only :( ) together - without any page breaks

Can we do this without any programming? If not, can someone point to example source code - where merger is demonstrated ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool to combine separate reports automatically.

The simplest way to combine multiple reports into a single report is to copy and paste the report items from the layout tab (Tables, Charts, Cross Tabs etc) of each of the original reports into the layout tab of the combined report.

You can force page breaks between different report items on the Page Break section of the Properties tab within the Property Editor for the relevant report items.

You will need to ensure that the combined report has all required data sources, data sets and report parameters - these can be transferred from the original reports by copying and pasting from the Data Explorer within the original reports, into the Data Explorer in the combined report.

Comment: But this solution assumes that all the items can be fit into a combined report - which is not the case. Example : We cannot create a single report of all the BIRT samples provided in eclipse - since the will not fit in a single layout... Is there no concept of multi-page layout ?

Comment: They can - just paste them in below the existing items. The layout will extend to accept the additional items; when viewing in layout or preview, they will appear to be on the same page, but when viewing the report in a specified format they will be paged appropriately.